# Emacs: embed Graphviz diagrams in Markdown documents

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode, graphviz

I've often used org-mode for writing documents that mix code & diagrams & explanatory text.  Now I'm wondering whether a similar thing is possible with `markdown-mode` - is there a way to put some embedded GraphViz code in a Markdown document, then have some key combo that processes the diagram and outputs a PNG in the local directory, and then will embed the PNG in the output?  If so, I could skip the `.org` step.

My main use case here is to create README files for Git repositories in GitHub or Atlassian Stash, FWIW.

Comment: That is possible with asciidoctor through https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-diagram if you feel like upgrading markup languages ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately ASCIIDoc{tor} I think isn't generally supported as a README format for Git repos, so that wouldn't help.

Comment: Yes it is: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/master/README.adoc

Comment: Oh - it doesn't look like it's supported in Stash: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pirateninjaunicorn.stash.readme-parser .  Maybe that could be added if it's a common format.

Comment: I hope, I think it is more than "common": https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor.org/issues/270

Comment: There is an open issue to add support for it, you can cast your vote for it: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-38863